# Auto set specific attribute term value to purchased products on Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

I want to automatically add a specific attribute value (which was previously set up) to ordered products when the order is placed and has "on-hold" status.

I sell unique products and I have set up the "STOCK" attribute and the "Out Of Stock" (out-of-stock) value.

When an order is placed and has "on-hold" status, I want to automatically change the featured status of the ordered products and also to add the out-of-stock attribute value to it.

The featured part is done and works, but I can't figure out how to add a specific attribute value to the products.

Here's my code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_on-hold', 'order_status_on_hold_update_products', 20, 2);

function order_status_on_hold_update_products( $order_id, $order ) {
  foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
    $product = $item->get_product();
    $product->set_featured(true);
    $product->set_attributes(???); // I don't know if and how set_attributes() should be used
    $product->save();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To set stock status "Out of Stock" you will use the `WC_Product` method `set_stock_status()` this way:

```
 $product->set_stock_status('outofstock'); // Or "instock"
 $product->save();
```

To set a product attribute term in your hooked function *(work for variable products too)*:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_on-hold', 'order_status_on_hold_update_products', 20, 2);
function order_status_on_hold_update_products( $order_id, $order ) {
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
        $product = $item->get_product();

        // Handling variable products
        $_product = $product->is_type('variation') ? wc_get_product( $item->get_product_id() ) : $product;

        $_product->set_featured( true );

        // Your product attribute settings
        $taxonomy   = 'pa_stock'; // The taxonomy
        $term_name  = "Out Of Stock"; // The term

        $attributes = (array) $_product->get_attributes();
        $term_id    = get_term_by( 'name', $term_name, $taxonomy )->term_id;

        // 1) If The product attribute is set for the product
        if( array_key_exists( $taxonomy, $attributes ) ) {
            foreach( $attributes as $key => $attribute ){
                if( $key == $taxonomy ){
                    $attribute->set_options( array( $term_id ) );
                    $attributes[$key] = $attribute;
                    break;
                }
            }
            $_product->set_attributes( $attributes );
        }
        // 2. The product attribute is not set for the product
        else {
            $attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();

            $attribute->set_id( sizeof( $attributes) + 1 );
            $attribute->set_name( $taxonomy );
            $attribute->set_options( array( $term_id ) );
            $attribute->set_position( sizeof( $attributes) + 1 );
            $attribute->set_visible( true );
            $attribute->set_variation( false );
            $attributes[] = $attribute;

            $_product->set_attributes( $attributes );
        }

        $_product->save();

        // Append the new term in the product
        if( ! has_term( $term_name, $taxonomy, $_product->get_id() ) )
            wp_set_object_terms($_product->get_id(), $term_slug, $taxonomy, true );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). it should works.

Comment: the Out Of Stock attribute value was more like an example, even though I am using it as an attribute for a special, different purpose. Thus, I don't want to just set the stock status, but to add a specific attribute value to the product. So you're saying that "set_attributes()" is not working for my case? Basically, I'm not setting a new custom attribute, but I simply want to add an already existing attribute value to the products from "on-hold" orders.

Comment: For example, if I have "Color" as attribute and "Red", "Green" and "Blue" as values, I want to automatically add the "Red" value to the products from on-hold orders.

Comment: Thank you. I will try now and revert. Just to be clear...I only need the part "1) If The product attribute is set for the product", right? Because the attribute is already existing and it has ONLY ONE Value. I just want this single attribute value to be added to the product once the product is ordered.

Comment: @RobertPopescu You can keep what you need in the code… That is the way to do it.

Comment: Ok, I don't really understand some lines from your code and what they do exactly, but I tested the whole thing as it is and it works as intended. This is exactly what I wanted to obtain. Can't thank you enough, kind Sir!

Comment: @RobertPopescu Product attributes are something complicated… So next time the easy way is to use a custom meta field (post meta data) that can be set and updated very easily.

Comment: Can you please share a link or some article where I could learn how to use custom meta fields as intended for my purpose?

Comment: @RobertPopescu The simplest example: you can set a custom field to a product (from its product ID) using `update_post_meta( $product_id, '_your_custom_meta_key', 'Out of Stock' );` and to get the value from the product iD you will use `$value = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_your_custom_meta_key', true );`