# Attributes added with Woocommerce methods not Linked Properly

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

This is not a duplicate question of threads like:

- [Add a new term to a product attribute and set it in the product in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53705122/add-a-new-term-to-a-product-attribute-and-set-it-in-the-product-in-woocommerce)
- [Auto set specific attribute term value to purchased products on Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53944532/auto-set-specific-attribute-term-value-to-purchased-products-on-woocommerce)

The problem here is not adding the attributes per say. The problem is associating the added attribute options with the proper terms I guess. As can be seen in the pictures below, the attribute options are set correctly but they are not associated with their terms (as seen in picture one [text instead of the gray background attribute option as seen in picture three]) even though I manually run set_object_terms for each product and the relationship is set properly in the database.

```
foreach($terms as $term_id) {
    $term = get_term( $term_id );
    $term_name = $term->name;
    $term_taxonomy = $term->taxonomy;
    $term_slug = $term->slug;
                            
    if( ! has_term( $term_name, $term_taxonomy, $parent_id ) ) {
        $set_terms = wp_set_object_terms($parent_id, $term_slug, $term_taxonomy, true );
    }
                            
}
```

While working on transferring some attributes from one database to another I'm facing an issue with the fact that attributes are being transferred correctly but they are saved in text form...

[image]

and I need to manually click "Save attributes" in wordpress admin > product edit...

[image]

for it to actually register correctly in the system as can be seen here.

[image]

The main issue is that while in text form as shown in the first screenshot, the attributes are not actually visible in the user facing shop and they are not available in the product's variations either.

I'm using woocommerce methods to update the products. Here's a code sample:

```
$attribute_object = new WC_Product_Attribute();
$attribute_object->set_name( $attribute_name );
$attribute_object->set_options( $value );
$attribute_object->set_visible(1);
$attribute_object->set_variation(1);
$attribute_object->set_position(0);
$attribute_object->set_id( 0 );
$new_product_attributes[$attribute_name] = $attribute_object;
$new_product->set_attributes($new_product_attributes);
                        
$new_product->save();
```

> How can I get WP to sync the product with it's newly added
> attributes/attribute values?
>
> What is the difference between the attribute options as seen in
> picture one and those in picture three (with the gray background)?

SIMPLE CODE TO REPRODUCE THE ISSUE

```
<?php
require_once(rtrim($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '/') . '/wp-load.php');

global $wpdb;
wp_cache_flush();


$objProduct = new WC_Product_Variable();

$objProduct->set_name("Product Title");
$objProduct->set_status("publish");  // can be publish,draft or any wordpress post status
$objProduct->set_catalog_visibility('visible'); // add the product visibility status
$objProduct->set_description("Product Description");
$objProduct->set_sku("product-sku"); //can be blank in case you don't have sku, but You can't add duplicate sku's
$objProduct->set_price(10.55); // set product price
$objProduct->set_regular_price(10.55); // set product regular price
$objProduct->set_manage_stock(true); // true or false
$objProduct->set_stock_quantity(10);
$objProduct->set_stock_status('instock'); // in stock or out of stock value
$objProduct->set_backorders('no');
$objProduct->set_sold_individually(false);

$product_attributes = [];
$attribute_list = array('pa_marime' => array('l','m')); // -- choose any existing taxonomy and two existing attribute options belonging to that taxonomy (terms)

foreach($attribute_list as $attribute_name => $value) {
    $attribute_object = new WC_Product_Attribute();
    $attribute_object->set_name( $attribute_name );
    $attribute_object->set_options( $value );
    $attribute_object->set_visible( 1 );
    $attribute_object->set_variation( 1 );
    $attribute_object->set_id( 0 );
    $product_attributes[$attribute_name] = $attribute_object;
}

$objProduct->set_attributes($product_attributes);

$product_id = $objProduct->save();

$terms_list = [];

foreach($attribute_list as $attribute_name => $value) {
    foreach($value as $val) {
        $term = term_exists($val, $attribute_name);
        if($term) {
            array_push($terms_list, $term['term_id']);
        }
    }
}

foreach($terms_list as $term_id) {
    $term = get_term( $term_id );
    $term_name = $term->name;
    $term_taxonomy = $term->taxonomy;
    $term_slug = $term->slug;
    
    if( ! has_term( $term_name, $term_taxonomy, $product_id ) ) {
        $set_terms = wp_set_object_terms($product_id, $term_slug, $term_taxonomy, true );   
    }
    
}
```

Tested the code in a Wordpress installation with the following specifications:

WP Version: 5.4.2
Woocommerce Version: 4.2.0

Probably works on other versions as well.

================== EDIT: ADDITIONAL DETAILS ==========================

I figured out that basically what happens is that upon setting the attributes woocommerce does not recognize the attribute options as taxonomies.

```
Array
(
    [pa_marime] => Array
        (
            [name] => pa_marime
            [value] => 1444 | 1445
            [position] => 0
            [is_visible] => 1
            [is_variation] => 1
            [is_taxonomy] => 0
        )

)
```

So now the question is:

What is the correct format to provide in WC_Product_Attribute() ->set_options() for the set_attributes method to recognize the values as taxonomies?

I have tried:

```
$values = array(term_1_id, term_2_id); // array of existing term ids
$values = array('term_1_id' => 'term_1_name', 'term_2_id' => 'term_2_name'); // array of existing term_id and term_name pairs
$values = array('term_1_name', 'term_2_name); // array of existing term names
$values = array('term_1_slug', 'term_2_slug); // array of existing term slugs
```

All of the above result in wc_product->set_attributes not recognizing them as taxonomies even though they are valid terms/taxonomies.

Comment: The problem could be simply in set_options( $value ); where $value requires to be an array of the term ids…

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. The $value array can be either filled with term IDs or term names as per woocommerce documentation. I'm using term names right now as can be seen in the images. If I fill it with term IDs the same thing happens except this time when I click save attributes in wp-admin now the term IDs are created as terms. (It treats them as term names and creates new terms, taxonomies and so on)

Comment: *"The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem."*** See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Fair enough. Added code to reproduce the issue entirely. Have a look if you get the chance. Any feedback is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling over this problem, using set_options the termid array must hold the values as ints, not strings.