# Modifying attributes in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to modify attributes from my plugin. I don't know why it's this hard because the task is simple: take a product, set its attributes and save the product...

I have a *Matière* attribute with the *mat* slug that has a few terms like *maille grattée* (*mg* slug), *piqué classique* (*pc* slug)...
I have another *Composition* attribute that has the *compo* slug. It has 2 terms : *100% coton* with the *1s1* slug and *50% coton / 50% polyester* with the *1s2* slug.

There's also a third attribute but it remains unused.
For some reason, this code doesn't want to work:

```
$product = wc_get_product(28);
$attributes = array('pa_mat' => 'mg', 'pa_compo' => '1s1');
$product->set_attributes($attributes);
$product->save();
```

I also tried

```
$product = wc_get_product(28);
$attributes = array('mat' => 'mg', 'compo' => '1s1');
$product->set_attributes($attributes);
$product->save();
```

which also doesn't work.
I'm frustrated as I don't see any errors so if you just know a way to get them, I would be happy to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to send array of WC_Product_Attribute to function. You can use it as an example - [Auto set specific attribute term value to purchased products on Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53944532/auto-set-specific-attribute-term-value-to-purchased-products-on-woocommerce)

Comment: Thank you, it worked but I had to modify a bit the function to get it to work for my case. If someone is interested, send me a message.